# Laravel: If isActive Middleware return false I can't login with different user until delete cookies

Tags: laravel, middleware

I have isActive middleware where I set 1 to acitive and 0 when user is not active.

```
isActive.php inMiddleware folder look like this:

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class IsActive
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
          if (Auth::user()->isActive()) {
            return $next($request);
          }
        }

        return redirect('/')->with('nonActive', 'Account is not active');
    }
}
```

and I have method in User model:

```
public function isActive()
{
    if ($this->is_active == 1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

In Kernel.php in protected $routeMiddleware I add this:

```
'is.active' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsActive::class,
```

and I have group middleware in routes and all this works fine.

But, when isActive Middleware return false I can't login with different user. Always get return false as if that user is inactive too until I delete cookies. After deleting I can login just fine with user that is active.

Comment: It sounds like you need to logout then login.

Comment: But I can't logout if I'm not login in a first place.

Comment: Change your if to `if(Auth::check && Auth::user()->isActive())` php is short circuiting.

Comment: Ok, I will, but still problem exist :)

Comment: I think the problem might be that this middleware is blocking authentication, essentially you can't `re-login` because this middleware won't let you. Your options are to logout before attempting to login again or move the IsActive middleware underneath the authentication middleware so that you can login again without logging out.

Answer (score 1):

Your route group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    // your active and auth user routes
});
```

If you want a user to be active in order to authenticate, use a global scope in your User model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class User extends Model
{
    ...
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('isactive', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('is_active', '=', 1);
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

This way a user will not be found unless they are active and you won't need the IsActive middleware.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#global-scopes

To customize authentication failure errors override `sendFailedLoginResponse` in your `LoginController`

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    return redirect('/')->with('nonActive', 'Account is not active');
}
```

Comment: But, I don't have nonActive user routes so I don't understand what to put there, if user is not active (is_active column is 0) the simply not suppose to login. All else routes shold be in ['middleware'=>'is.active'] group. Also have admin and super.admin group but that not related to question.

Comment: No, if I add that to User mode, error appear: Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\User::App\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Builder, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\kapCMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 921

Comment: @NenadM you will need `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;` I've updated the answer.

Comment: That work and now is working fine but new problem is that isActive middleware seems no more working because message 'Account is not active" not appear. Now instead of "Account is not active" message I get as that user username or password is not true.

Comment: @NenadM If I understand your requirement correctly you do not want users to be able to authenticate if they are not active? If this is the case the IsActive Middleware is no longer necessary.  You can customize your authentication errors as necessary to display "Account is not active" if the user cannot log in.

Comment: You mean after ->where('is_active', '=', 1) to add ->with('nonActive', 'Account is not active') ?

Comment: @NenadM No, I have updated the answer with additional details.

Comment: Now I don't have a message if I make a mistake with username or password, now it says "Account is not active" instead of username or password is not true :) Eitherway, I'm not sure that in this way I will no longer have usage of groups in routes since I use two more groups...

Comment: @NenadM From your first comment, you consider inactive users `not` authenticated, I think the original invalid username/password is sufficient in this case which would render the override of the response useless.

Comment: @adam Middleware is definitely the best place for this type of check.  With remember me tokens, an inactive user could continue to use the system for weeks without having to re-login with this method.

Comment: @Devon According to Nenad an inactive user is essentially a user that doesn't exist `if user is not active (is_active column is 0) the simply not suppose to login`, which is why I proposed the global scope. If his solution offered a varied path for inactive users, a middleware would make sense here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't redirect if Auth::check() returns false..

Change your logic around:

```
    if (Auth::check()) {
      if (!Auth::user()->isActive()) {
        return redirect('/')->with('nonActive', 'Account is not active');
      }
    }

    return $next($request);
```

You could also simplify that to one if statement.  You may also consider logging the user out before you redirect.

Comment: It doesn't work, still shows for all accounts that is not active either some is active.

Comment: If it's redirecting with this code when the user is active, then your problem lies with your isActive() method.  Debug and make sure everything is set properly.